# Can concepts be used with template template parameters?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Let us consider following code:

```
#include <concepts>

template<typename X>
struct Concrete_M {
  X f() const { return X{}; }
};

struct Concrete_X {};

template<typename T, typename X>
concept M = requires (T t)
  {
   { t.f() } -> std::convertible_to<X>;
  };

template<M<Concrete_X>>
struct C {};

const C<Concrete_M<Concrete_X>> c{};
```

Can I use following template template parameter `T`?

```
template<template<typename> typename T, typename X>
concept M = requires (T<X> t)
  {
   { t.f() } -> std::convertible_to<X>;
  };
```

How should I change

```
template<M<Concrete_X>>
struct C {};

const C<Concrete_M<Concrete_X>> c{};
```

to properly use updated concept `M`? I am looking for something like this:

```
template<typename X, /* ... */>
struct C {};

const C<Concrete_X, /* ... */> c{};
```

but I don't understand what should I put instead of `/* ... */` comments. I tried:

```
template<typename X, M<X>>
struct C {};

const C<Concrete_X, Concrete_M<Concrete_X>> c{};
```

but GCC 10.0.1 raises an error:

> (...) ‘M’ does not constrain a type (...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shorter hand *type-constraint* syntax for concepts:

```
template <Concept T>
struct C { };
```

is only valid for those cases where `Concept`'s first template parameter is a type parameter. When that is not the case, you have to simply use the long form syntax: a *requires-clause*:

```
template <template <typename> class Z>
    requires M<Z, Concrete_X>
struct C {};
```

The equivalent longer-form for my initial example is:

```
template <typename T> requires Concept<T>
struct C { };
```

The long form and short form mean the same thing - there's no functionality different here.