# c++20 implement an interface for a vector

Tags: c++, vector, c++-concepts

I'd like to create a class with can use any Vector.

Possible types could be std::vector, boost::vector, etl::vector.

All used vector types must implement std::vector member functions.
I'd like to create a concept which validates that the used vector type implements all std::vector member functions

So far I have come up with

```
#include <concepts>
#include <vector>

template < typename T , typename Element_T>
concept IVector_T = requires(T vec, Element_T elem)
{
  {vec.push_back(elem) } -> std::same_as<void>;  ///< Add an element to the vector
  {vec.back()} ->std::convertible_to<Element_T>;
};

template<typename Element_T, IVector_T Vector_T>
class TestVector
{
public:
  void push_back(const Element_T& elem)
  {
    myVec.push_back(elem);
  }
  Element_T& back()
  {
    //return ref to last element
    return myVec.back();
  }
private:
  Vector_T<Element_T> myVec;
};
```

However I'm getting a compiler error

```
<source>(27): error C2059: syntax error: '<'
<source>(28): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'TestVector<Element_T,Vector_T>' being compiled
<source>(27): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
<source>(19): error C3861: 'myVec': identifier not found
<source>(19): error C2065: 'myVec': undeclared identifier
```

I'm using latest MSVC17 on Win 10, however this should also run an Linux and Mac

I have a godbolt link for you to easily reproduce this issue
https://godbolt.org/z/54zac583j

Thx for your help guys :)

Edit:
As noted in the comments pop_into() is not std. => replaced it with back().

To clearify: Some vectors like boost::vector and std::vector need 1 template argument (i.e. std::vector)
Other vector types like etl::vector may need more template arguments. etl::vector for example is a preallocated vector therefore we need a max vector size (i.e. etl::vector<int, 100>)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can concepts be used with template template parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363891/can-concepts-be-used-with-template-template-parameters)

Comment: Is `Vector_T` a template template parameter?

Comment: Also what's `pop_into`? Did you mean `pop_back`?

Comment: `IVector_T` has an extra template parameter `Element_T`. This is probably not what you want. Require that `T::value_type` is a type and use it instead.

Comment: sorry my fault. Replace pop_into(). and yes Vector_T is a template teplate paramter. Types of Vector_T could be std::vector<T> and etl::vector<T, MAX_VEC_SIZE>

Comment: @n.m. how can i use T::value_type in that context?

Comment: See [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aex6EfTzW). Note it works very differently from all suggested solutions. In this demo, you always work with `std::vector<int>`, not two separate entities `std::vector` and `int` or `std::vector<int>` and `int` or whatever. In the demo the vector doesn't even have to be an instantiation of a template. Or it can be an instantiation of a template with more parameters. It is a *type*, not a template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do template instantiation of `Vector_T` like this.

```
template<typename Element_T, IVector_T<Element_T> Vector_T>
class TestVector
{
...
private:
    Vector_T myVec;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you plan to instantiate this type, but given the member variable, I suspect you didn't properly specify the template arguments:

```
template<typename Element_T, template <typename> typename Vector_T>
requires(IVector_T<Vector_T<Element_T>, Element_T>)
class TestVector { // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a more explicit syntax. This compiles:

```
template<typename Element_T,
         template <typename Elem> typename Vector_T>
requires IVector_T<Vector_T<Element_T>, Element_T>
class TestVector
{
...
```

(I have not tried to compile one of its instantiations, though.)

Your `Vector_T` is a template, so I think it's required to explicitly make `TestVector` into a "template template".

Further, `IVector_T` requires two arguments, so using `template <IVector_T Vector_T>` is incorrect: what would the other argument be?